Is there a way to decode transactions fetched from getBlock so that i get some details like amount, source, destination?
I am trying to fetch blocks and iterate over transaction - both native SOL and SPL program transactions.
parsing SOL transaction is pretty straight forward.
however how do i do the same thing for SPL program transactions.
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, decodeTransferInstruction } from '@solana/spl-token';

const block = await connection.getBlock(slot, { maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0 });
for (const transaction of block.transactions) {
  const { meta } = transaction || {};
  const { message, signatures } = transaction?.transaction || {};
  const accountKeys = message.getAccountKeys();
  for (const instruction of message?.instructions) {
    let decodedInstruction;
    try {
      decodedInstruction = decodeTransferInstruction(instruction);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      return null;
    }
    const { keys, data } = decodedInstruction || {};
    const { mint, amount } = data || {};

    if (
      !keys?.source ||
      !keys?.destination ||
      !amount ||
      amount < 0 ||
      mint !== mintAddress
    ) {
      return null;
    }

    const source = accountKeys.get(keys.source.pubkey.toString());
    const destination = accountKeys.get(keys.destination.pubkey.toString());
  }
}

this is what i am trying currently
but i always get an error in decodeTransferInstruction
not sure what i am missing.

It's hard to know for sure without seeing the transaction you're trying to parse, but I think the issue is that return null; in the catch. That means that as soon as you read an instruction that is not a token transfer instruction you're going to exit the function this for loop is in. You probably want continue; instead, which will move to the next iteration of the loop.
Your transaction probably has something like a compute budget instruction as the first instruction, with the token transfer instruction coming later.

I was trying to figure a way to parse the transactions in a more general way not per transaction i thought maybe where's a simple way.
